# Resolving website name correctly in Tomcat

Tags: url, tomcat, web, resolve

My httpd file in Apache as proxy looks like below:

```
<IfModule mod_proxy.c>
   ProxyRequests On
   ProxyPass         /SYL  http://www.mywebsitename.com:8080/SYL
   ProxyPassReverse  /SYL  http://www.mywebsitename.com:8080/SYL

   <Location "/">
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
   </Location>

   <Proxy *>
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
   </Proxy>
```

In Tomcat, my `server.xml` looks like below:

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="8443"
           proxyPort="80"
           proxyName="www.mywebsitename.com" />
```

What's happening is that, in the browser, when I type www.mywebsitename.com, it shows only the Apache Welcome page but when I type www.mywebsitename.com/SYL, it shows the website welcome page.

What I want is that the www.mywebsitename.com should resolve to www.mywebsitename.com/SYL.